# Has anyone use SmartyStreets in a PeopleSoft page for address validation?

Tags: peoplesoft, smartystreets

We have a subscription with SmartyStreets and have used successfully with MSSql.Net, but want to apply to a PeopleSoft page for address validation and formating.   Any code suggestions would be helpful?  Does it have to go through PSoft integration broker? (not very experienced on IB)  Any security issues to deal with?  We use Oracle database, on a Unix operating system. 
Thanks in advance for any assist.  Marsha

Comment: SmartyStreets' API is just a regular HTTP request. Even though I'm a developer at SmartyStreets, I haven't used PeopleSoft before so I can't help with code samples, but just make sure to consider the usual security issues: use your Secret Keys (found in account pages) when the key won't be exposed to users of the application. Otherwise use the HTML identifiers which pair with an authorized domain name. Try Googling HTTP GET (or POST) request with PeopleCode and see if anything helpful turns up.